# Rename from CSV Script renames files but trys to repeat process

Tags: file, powershell, csv

I have a script which renames files taken from a CSV but it throws an error when it trys to re-rename files after it has already carried out the successful proceedure

CSV file is like:

```
old      new
AC100    DC100
AC101    DC102
```

Code tried:

```
$sourceDir = read-host "Please enter source Dir:"
$csvL = $sourceDir + "\files.csv"
$csv = import-csv $csvL
$files = get-childitem $sourceDir
$csv | % {
            ForEach( $file in $files){
            if($file = $_.old){

            $old = $sourceDir + "\" + $_.old

            Rename-Item $old $_.new
                    }       
                }
            }
```

I beleive it is something to do with looping and the csv but im not sure where im going wrong, i have had similar issue before.

Here is a sample of the error.

```
+             Rename-Item  <<<< $old $_.new
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\scripts\2039X.67438.TXT' does not exist.
At C:\scripts\renamerTim.ps1:18 char:15
+             Rename-Item  <<<< $old $_.new
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\scripts\2039X.67438.TXT' does not exist.
At C:\scripts\renamerTim.ps1:18 char:15
+             Rename-Item  <<<< $old $_.new
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\scripts\2039X.67438.TXT' does not exist.
At C:\scripts\renamerTim.ps1:18 char:15
+             Rename-Item  <<<< $old $_.new
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\scripts\2039X.67438.TXT' does not exist.
At C:\scripts\renamerTim.ps1:18 char:15
+             Rename-Item  <<<< $old $_.new
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\scripts\2039X.67438.TXT' does not exist.
At C:\scripts\renamerTim.ps1:18 char:15
+             Rename-Item  <<<< $old $_.new
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\scripts\2039X.67438.TXT' does not exist.
At C:\scripts\renamerTim.ps1:18 char:15
+             Rename-Item  <<<< $old $_.new
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\scripts\2039X.67438.TXT' does not exist.
At C:\scripts\renamerTim.ps1:18 char:15
+             Rename-Item  <<<< $old $_.new
```

thanks in advance,
Craig

Comment: if($file = $_.old) maybe is if($file -eq $_.old). Post your errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `ForEach( $file in $files)` is redundant, since you already traverse each "file" with the `$csv | % {` command. I'd try something like:

```
$csv | Foreach-Object { //I prefer to print the full commands in scripts
    $oldfile = $sourcedir + "\" + $_.old
    if (Test-Path $oldfile)
    {
        Rename-Item $oldfile ($sourcedir + "\" + $_.new)
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose it will work as it will run the rename-item on the working directory. I will give that a bash

Answer (score 1):

You have a redundant nested loop.  `$csv | %{ ... }` will already loop through file in the csv, and then the foreach loops through each file in the folder.

Try this:

```
  $sourceDir = read-host "Please enter source Dir:"
  $csvL = $sourceDir + "\files.csv"
  $csv = import-csv $csvL
  $files = get-childitem $sourceDir
  $csv | % {
     $oldpath = join-path $sourcedir $_.old
     $newpath = join-path $sourcedir $_.new

     rename-item $oldpath $newpath
  }
```

Comment: Thank you that is the conclusion I came to after tbergstedt's comment. However the join-path cmdlet looks like a powerful feature which I am going to encorporate in to future scripts. Thank you for taking the time to look at this, much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I was testing my code when tbergstedt posted his comment.  I decided to post anyway in case it was useful - I'm glad it was :) .