# Renaming files in directory using new names from csv file

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, powershell-cmdlet, import-csv, rename-item-cmdlet

I'm looking for help in creating a script that can rename all of the files contained in a directory to a table referenced in a csv file. For example, I have a folder with random file names and I also have a csv file with the current file names in column A, and what the actual file name should be changed to in column B.

I thought about using something along the lines of:

`get-childitem *pdf -force | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace((Import-Csv -path .\List.csv).filename, (Import-Csv -Path .\List.csv).newfilename) }`

Note that *filename* & *newfilename* refer to column **A** and **B** respectively.

Nothing really happens when I run this script. I'm a novice with powershell so I've come to the limits of my knowledge of how to accomplish this task. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you all!

Comment: Does the CSV file contain full paths of the files or just the file names?

Comment: @AdminOfThings just the file names, but I could modify the spreadsheet to contain the file paths (for both current and new names) as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell - find file by 'file name' and rename based on CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287924/powershell-find-file-by-file-name-and-rename-based-on-csv)

Comment: @Theo Not really, I went through that post and the answers didn't really do much for my current scenario

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following if you are in the directory that contains the target files and the CSV file. This assumes you have headers in your CSV named `filename` and `newfilename`.

```
$TargetDir = Resolve-Path -Path .
Import-Csv -Path .\List.csv | Foreach-Object {
    $Src = Join-Path -Path $TargetDir -ChildPath $_.filename
    $Dst = Join-Path -Path $TargetDir -ChildPath $_.newfilename
    Rename-Item -Path $Src -NewName $Dst
}
```

If the target directory is another location, you can simply modify the `Join-Path` statements to use `-Path`.

```
$TargetDir = 'c:\folder'
Import-Csv -Path .\List.csv | Foreach-Object {
    $Src = Join-Path -Path $TargetDir -ChildPath $_.filename
    $Dst = Join-Path -Path $TargetDir -ChildPath $_.newfilename
    Rename-Item -Path $Src -NewName $Dst
}
```

**Note:** If the CSV file does not contain headers, you will need to either utilize the `-Header` switch in `Import-Csv` like in [Glenn's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59533226/11025476) or add the column headers to the CSV.

Comment: Better answer than mine.

Comment: There are elements to both answers that are useful.

Comment: Sorry gentlemen, there must be something I'm doing wrong or have different in the spreadsheet. I ran this script and got the following error message:

Rename-Item : Cannot rename the item at 'C:\Users\ZZZZZZ\Desktop\Name Testing' because it is in use.
At line:4 char:5
+     Rename-Item -Path $Src -NewName $Dst

Comment: @Ric.Mart I made some code edits to make the experience more similar in the two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's no header in the .csv and it only contains the file names, this might work for you:

```
# Only import the CSV once
$csvData = Import-Csv .\List.csv -Header "Old","New"

# Remove the -WhatIf after testing
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { 
    $file = $_
    $csvData | Where-Object { 
        $_.Old -eq $file.Name 
    } | ForEach-Object { 
        Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName $_.New -WhatIf 
    } 
}
```

Or a more concise implementation:

```
$csvData = Import-Csv .\List.csv -Header "Old","New"
dir | %{ $file = $_; $csvData | ?{ $_.Old -eq $file.Name } | %{ Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName $_.New -WhatIf } }
```

Comment: I ran the script with and without the -whatif  parameter and it doesn't look like anything happened. Should I include headers like "Old" and "New"?

Comment: there was a mistake in my last edit (had `%{ $_.Old -eq $file.Name }` instead of `?{ $_.Old -eq $file.Name }`).  If you still don't see any output, it may not be finding a match for the filenames.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of example with some test data I threw together: 
https://i.imgur.com/6nvOBjc.png

Answer (score 0):

**================ NEW ANSWER WITH A SIMPLE SCRIPT ================**

Tested on MacOS:

Just create a file named **map.csv** and format it like this:

```
old_file1.txt,new_file1.txt
old_file2.txt,new_file2.txt
old_file3.txt,new_file3.txt
```

create a shell script **rename.sh** and change the variables folder_path, csv_file and file_extension:

```
#!/bin/bash

folder_path="path/to/your/files/"
csv_file="path/to/map/file/map.csv"
file_extension=".jpg"

while IFS=',' read -r old_file new_file
do
  mv "${folder_path}/${old_file}${file_extension}" "${folder_path}/${new_file}${file_extension}"
  echo "File ${old_file}${file_extension} renamed to ${new_file}${file_extension}."
done < "$csv_file"
```

start the script with `sh rename.sh`

and enjoy the magic ;-)